# Generate 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404

I created a action called `error404` in the controller `PagesController`. I would like to display this action if the following situation occurred:

1. The controller in URL does not exist
2. The action in URL does not exist

How can I accomplish this?

I tried to follow the instructions on this page, [Show a 404 instead of 500 in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553365/show-a-404-instead-of-500-in-rails) , but that only seems to work with the first situation.

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if action in your controller is not existed and your controller is due to the scaffold generation then by default it goes to the 'show' method of a controller.

For Ex;:-  http://www.domain.com/controller_name/invalid_action_name

Here your "controller_name"  is valid Controller.  &

"invalid_action_name" is invalid action.

Then by default it goes to the 'show' method of "controller_name" & considered "invalid_action_name" as a params[:id].

so in show method you can rescue the error and can show the valid error page such as "Record not found"  or "error 404"

EDITED
you have to add route for a new method name in your /config/routes.rb as follows

```
map.resources :controller_name, :collection=>{:show=>:get}
```

don't forget to restart a server whenever you change this file.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to RoR and not quite understand.

I created a new action called "show". When I hit the invalid_action_name, it didn't go into the action "show". It just give me....

Unknown action
No action responded to invalid_action_name. Actions: xxxx, xxxx, xxx

Is that I made anything wrong?

Comment: you have to add route to your routes.rb. please look into my Edited Answer.

Comment: oops. it's not working for me. but thanks for your help anyway. :)